# How to unit test a custom XMLHttpRequest-based progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, xmlhttprequest

I would like to unit test a custom XHR function that's used on a jQuery AJAX request to drive a progress bar showing upload/download progress. I'm using Sinon.js useFakeXMLHttpRequest to test other aspects of this code, including the AJAX request itself, but (if I understand correctly) useFakeXMLHttpRequest would replace my custom XHR function rather than testing it. What would be some useful approaches to consider for unit testing the custom XHR function itself?

Here is the custom XHR function that I want to unit test:

```
function xhr() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            doProgressBar(event.loaded / event.total * 50);
        }
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            doProgressBar(50 + event.loaded / event.total * 50);
        }
    }, false);

    return xhr;
}
```

And here is the jQuery AJAX request that uses it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/my/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foo: bar }),
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError,
    xhr: xhr
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: My first thought: php starts working, and doesn't return anything untill its completely done, so any value of progress is pretty meaningless.  I'm not sure about other server languages.  I only mean: these are the considerations you want to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks. With this code in JavaScript on Chrome (at least), I'm getting progress updates when upload completes and response download completes, which is perfectly adequate for my purposes. It effectively shows progress at 50% and 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I misunderstood something about Sinon: useFakeXMLHttpRequest doesn't replace my XHR function but rather its requests.

Here's my solution. First, refactor my custom XHR function slightly for testability:

```
function xhr(xhr) {
    xhr = xhr || new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    // ... otherwise same as above
}
```

Now implement the test (Mocha/BDD, Chai):

```
describe('custom XHR function', function() {
  var myXhr;

  before(function() {
    myXhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
    myXhr.requests = [];
    myXhr.onCreate = function(request) {
      // Call my custom XHR function with a fake request.
      // This adds the progress event listeners that drive the progress bar
      xhr(request); 
      myXhr.requests.push(request);
    };
  });

  after(function() {
    myXhr.restore();
  });

  it('should drive progress bar from 0 to 100%', function() {
    assert.strictEqual($progressBar.css('width'), '0%');

    assert.strictEqual(myXhr.requests.length, 0);
    doPost();
    assert.strictEqual(myXhr.requests.length, 1);

    // Respond OK
    myXhr.requests[0].respond(200, { }, '');
    assert.strictEqual($progressBar.css('width'), '100%');
  });
});
```

I hope this helps some else as well.